# Получение содержимого через preg_match

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

1) Как достать через preg_match все <p>, которые находятся внутри этого контейнера. <p> на сайте много.

```
  <div class="b-text clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
       <p>//Text</p>
  </div>
```

2) Как достать все содержимое дива с class="b-text clearfix" Внутри которого тоже могут быть дивы?

```
<div class="b-text clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
       <div>//Text</div>
       <div><p>/Text</p></div>
       <p>//Text</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Регулярные выражения — неподходящий инструмент для вашей задачи[.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Используйте честный парсер.

Comment: что значит "честный" парсер ?

Comment: @Zow: google "php parser html" -> [PHP Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) -> документация ->

    $html = file_get_html('http://your.uri.here');
    foreach($html->find('div.b-text.clearfix') as $element)
        echo $element->innertext;

Comment: @VladD спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поиск будет идти только внутри контейнера, или по всему тексту где контейнеров много?

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/GAXUjc)

Comment: может быть и внутри где много контейнеров.

Comment: да но, если <p></p>  будут вне дива, то они тоже высонуться, но мне нужны только внутренние

Comment: Вам надо тогда сначала достать отдельно все контейнеры, а потом перебирать их по очереди и доставать из контейнеров <р>